# Statistics/Algorithm: How do I compare a weekly graph with its own history to see when in the past it was almost the same?

Tags: algorithm, graph, automation, statistics, data-modeling

I’ve got a statistical/mathematical problem I’m stumped on and I was really hoping to get some help. I’m working on a research where I need to compare a weekly graph with its own history to see when in the past it was almost the same. Think of this as “finding the closest match”. The information is displayed as a line graph, but it’s readily available as raw data:

- **Date...................Result**

  - 08/10/18......52.5
  - 08/07/18......60.2
  - 08/06/18......58.5
  - 08/05/18......55.4
  - 08/04/18......55.2
- and so on...

What I really want is the output to be a form of correlation between the current data points with the other set of 5 concurrent data points in history. So, something like:

- **Date range.....................Correlation**

  - 07/10/18-07/15/18....0.98

We’ll be getting a code written in Python for the software to do this automatically (so that as new data is added, it automatically runs and finds the closest set of numbers to match the current one).

Here’s where the difficulty sets in: Since numbers are on a general upward trend over time, we don’t want it to compare the absolute value (since the numbers might never really match). One suggestion has been to compare the delta (rate of change as a percentage over the previous day), or using a log scale.

I’m wondering: how do I go about this? What kind of calculation I can use to get the desired results? I’ve looked at the different kind of correlation equations, but they don’t account for the “shape” of the data, and they generally just average it out. The shape of the line chart is the important thing.

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would simply divide the data of each week by their average (i.e., normalize them to an average of 1), then sum the squares of the differences of each day of each pair of weeks. This sum is what you want to minimize.

If you don't care about how much a graph oscillates relative to its mean, you can normalize also the variance. For each week, calculate mean and variance, then subtract the mean and divide by the root of the variance. Each week will have mean 0 and variance 1. Then minimize the sum of squares of differences like before.

If the normalization of data is all you can change in your workflow, just leave out the sum of squares of differences minimization part.

Comment: Thanks Walter. I was also looking into Pearson's correlation coefficient. Would that work?

Comment: I don't see how you would do that. It doesn't look right to me, though (but keep in mind that I'm no statistics guy, I'm just a programmer with a degree in physics)